# How to deal with coma and oblique spherical aberration in a Czerny Turner configuration?

Tags: optics, spectroscopy, raman-spectroscopy

[image]

I am modelling my own spectrometer using Zemax when all of a sudden I've been told that:

> even if you manage to optimize the angles or positions of
>   the grating and the mirrors, you won't get good enough focal points on
>   the CCD because of geometrical aberrations like coma and (oblique)
>   spherical aberration. These come from the fact that you hit your
>   concave mirror at off-axis positions from off-axis points.

A [quick googling](http://www.horiba.com/us/en/scientific/products/optics-tutorial/monochromators-spectrographs/) reveals:

> Coma may be corrected at one wavelength in a CZ by calculating an
>   appropriate operating geometry as shown in Figure 7.

and

> The OPD due to astigmatism varies with the square of numerical
>   aperture and the square of the off­axis angle and cannot be corrected
>   without employing aspheric optics

1. How can one correct coma for a range of wavelengths then?
2. Where should one incorporate the aspheric optics in the Czerny Turner configuration?

Comment: Some Czerny-Turner imaging spectrometers use toroidal focusing mirrors (instead of spherical ones). [This article](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Dane_Austin/publication/26335467_Broadband_astigmatism-free_Czerny-Turner_imaging_spectrometer_using_spherical_mirrors/links/0912f5025382ea1d13000000.pdf) suggests a way to reduce aberrations using spherical mirrors, but I haven't read it through.

Answer (score 1):

1. you can't
2. astigmatism can be corrected for without aspheric optics, but in terms of final performance your dominant aberration will be spherical - roughly proportional to the cube of the entry light cone angle.  By adding an extra aspherical surface you can make what PI are calling a Schmidt Czerny Turner.  Schmidt design telescopes have used an extra aspheric surface for this purpose for a while.
   A toroidal mirror is still a type of spherical mirror (just with different radii in x and y) but it is used in most spectrographs to give better imaging performance - a non-toroidal C-T will turn a spot of light at the input into a vertical line at the detector - fine for use as a monochromator or with an SPD but not if spatial resolution is desirable for use with a CCD/sCMOS sensor for microspectroscopy or for multitrack spectroscopy.